# php Aruba $_session issue

Tags: php, session

I'm testing this code in Localhost and on Server "Aruba".

In local environment it works perfectly while **on Server I dont have the expected session value**

When I echo out the $_SESSION['lang'] it outputs :

-the correct country code (Ex.'en') in localhost

-On the Aruba server $_SESSION['lang'] outputs the array named $lang (that you can find on lang.en.php)instead of the needed country code!!

Where am I wrong?

thanks

Luca

my **home.php**

```
require_once('/web/htdocs/www.mywebsite.com/home/includes/langSwitcher.inc');
echo $_SESSION['lang'];
[..]
```

my **langSwitcher.inc**

```
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

if(isset($_GET['lang']))
{
$lang = $_GET['lang'];

// register the session and set the cookie
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}

else if(isset($_SESSION['lang']))
{
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];  
}

else if(isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
$_SESSION['lang']=$lang;
}
else
{
$lang = 'en';
$_SESSION['lang']=$lang;

}

switch ($lang) 
{
 case 'en':
 $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
 break;

 case 'it':
 $lang_file = 'lang.it.php';
 break; 

}

include_once $lang_file;
```

my **lang.en.php**

```
/*
-----------------
Language: Italian
-----------------
*/



$langcode='en';

$lang = array();

$lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = 'pagetitle';

$lang['HEADER_TITLE'] = 'title header ';

$lang['SITE_NAME'] = 'name site';

$lang['HEADING'] = 'title';
```

Comment: In lang.en.php hai scritto "Language: Italian"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `register_globals` may be enabled (although that feature is deprecated). You can find out by running a `phpinfo()` and looking for the `register_globals` entry.

Assuming it is enabled, the only solution is to fix it in `php.ini` (you cannot override `register_globals` with an `ini_set()` call).

Answer (score 0):

Well you are using $lang to keep the langcode, but also to store the array information. Perhaps in the langSwitcher.inc you should be using $langcode to store the session?

Because you are also settings the $lang var in the session their. On your server it seems to be using a reference to the $lang file, and therefor outputting the latest content set to $lang (which is the array) and on local it is storing the actual content of $lang.

Anyway, it can be solved by not using the same variable name to store two different items.